# Ng-if not working

Tags: angularjs

I have this (partial) view with its controller: my goal is to insert/remove the two subview (ADR and MDR) programmatically.

I studied ng-if directive and I tried to apply it in my test but seems not working well cause the views are not showed when I click on the link.

Any helps?

```js
drfmControllers.controller('functionalitiesHandler', ['$scope',

   function ($scope) {


       $scope.setMDRFunction = function() {
           clearAll();
           $scope.MDR = true;
           console.log("MDR "+$scope.MDR);
       }

       $scope.setADRFunction = function() {
           clearAll();
           $scope.ADR = true;
           console.log("ADR "+  $scope.ADR);
       }

       function clearAll(){
           $scope.MDR = false;
           $scope.ADR = false;
       }
    }
]);
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row content">
        <div class="col-sm-3 sidenav hidden-xs">
            <h2>DRFM Cockpit</h2>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li><a ng-controller="functionalitiesHandler"  ng-click="setMDRFunction()" >MDR</a></li>
                <li><a ng-controller="functionalitiesHandler"  ng-click="setADRFunction()" >ADR</a></li>

            </ul>
            <br>
        </div>
        <br>

        <div class="col-sm-9">           
            <div ng-if="MDR">
                <h1>Test 1</h1>
                <p>Test 1</p>
                <hr>
            </div>
           <div ng-if="ADR">
                <h1>Test 2</h1>
                <p>Test 2</p>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be useful if your snippet demonstrated the issue you're having rather than just syntax erroring because you've not included enough code.

Comment: @Jamiec its a big application so it is hard to replicate in Plunker or similar: so I put here only the most important pieces of code.

Comment: No, its not - and you dont need to replicate your whole application. What you need to do is include angular and define `drfmControllers`

Comment: Since you havent included the app config code, i cannot make the code to work, i suggest to print the MDR and ADR variable in dom like {{MDR}} and observe if the value changes, if the value changes then try this ng-if ="'MDR'" (add single quote to variable).

Comment: Hey Pietro, do you still have any other doubt in this question? If no, could you please set the answer to accepted? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ng-controller` attribute needs to be declared on a common ancestor of all the elements that rely on its $scope.  You have it declared twice, on the two `<li>` elements (which, incidentally, will create two different controller instances).  Try moving it up to the  `<div class="row content">` element.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the controller for the whole html so it wont get `MDR` and `ADR` `ng-if` values.

**You can handle it adding the ng-controller in the outer div and removing from your list.**

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="functionalitiesHandler">
```

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyp76wj1/6/) for demonstrating.

Comment: @PietroFragnito Nice that you made progress!

Answer (score 0):

the ng-controller="functionalitiesHandler"  should be declared in the parent div of all divs where you are refering the code from that controller. e.g. in this div:
    div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="functionalitiesHandler"